# How to compile JSPs via Maven, but without failing on errors?

Tags: maven, jsp, tomcat8

I've just started working on a large project that has many JSPs, many of which were created long ago, and some of which were generated.  I would like to use the [jetty-jspc-maven-plugin](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/jetty-jspc-maven-plugin.html) from org.eclipse.jetty to compile our JSPs for use in Tomcat 8.5.  Unfortunately, some of the JSPs do not compile cleanly, and when there is a compilation problem, the maven build fails and stops.

The [JspcMojo](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.4.7.v20170914/jetty-jspc-maven-plugin/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/jspc/plugin/JspcMojo.java) class does most of the work.  It has an embedded class, [JspcMojo.JettyJspC](https://www.eclipse.org/jetty/javadoc/current/org/eclipse/jetty/jspc/plugin/JspcMojo.JettyJspC.html) that extends `org.apache.jasper.JspC` and has a `failOnError` property.  The documentation for `JettyJspC` says, "JettyJspC Add some extra setters to standard JspC class to help configure it for running in maven."  So, it seems like I ought to be able to set the `failOnError` property to false and be done.  I have tried all of the following, without success.  How can I pass the `failOnError` property from maven to the JSP compiler?

```
<jspc.failOnError>false</jspc.failOnError>
<org.apache.jasper.compiler.failOnError>false</org.apache.jasper.compiler.failOnError>
<org.apache.jasper.JspC.failOnError>false</org.apache.jasper.JspC.failOnError>
<maven.compiler.failOnError>false</maven.compiler.failOnError>
<JettyJspC.failOnError>false</JettyJspC.failOnError>
<JspcMojo.JettyJspC.failOnError>false</JspcMojo.JettyJspC.failOnError>
<org.eclipse.jetty.jspc.plugin.JspcMojo.JettyJspC.failOnError>false</org.eclipse.jetty.jspc.plugin.JspcMojo.JettyJspC.failOnError>
```

BTW, [compiling JSPs using ant](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/jasper-howto.html#Web_Application_Compilation) is fairly well documented.  I want to do the equivalent using maven.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the `configuration` section, you can use a subelement of the `jspc` element, like so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
    <artifactId>jetty-jspc-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>9.4.7.v20170914</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>jspc</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>jspc</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <webAppSourceDirectory>${basedir}/target/overlaidjsps</webAppSourceDirectory>
                <webXml>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                <webXmlFragment>${basedir}/target/webfrag.xml</webXmlFragment>
                <!-- The comma separated list of patterns for file extensions to be processed. -->
                <includes>**/*.jsp</includes>
                <jspc><failOnError>false</failOnError></jspc>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```